# Auto populate item amount in custom field

Tags: netsuite

How to auto-populate item amount in custom field on cash sales.

I am new to client script and here is the snippet which i have tried but it doesn't function as expected.Please suggest.

```
function custItemAmount(type) 
{   
    if(type == 'edit')
    {
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
        var itemCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');

        for(i=1; i<=itemCount; i++)
        {
            //fetch amount of each item
            var item_amount=record.getLineItemValue('item', 'amount', i);
            if (item_amount != null && item_amount != '') {
                record.setLineItemValue('item', 'custbody_itemamount', i, item_amount);
                //set total amount to custom item amount field
            }
        }
        var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set the wrong field for the line item. Is `custbody_itemamount` really the field you want? Seems like a body field to me, not a line item field. I'd expect it be called `custcol_lineitemamount`

Comment: Typo..That is correct. It's custcol_lineitemamount. Do you see any issue with the script?

Comment: Is that field you want to populate is a body field or line item field ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the wrong field for the line item. Is `custbody_itemamount` really the field you want? Seems like a body field to me, not a line item field. I'd expect it be called `custcol_lineitemamount`

Try the following instead, though check to make sure the field names are correct, since I've made some assumptions.

```
{   
   if(type == 'edit')
   {
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
    var itemCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');

        for(i=1;i<=itemCount;i++)
        {
            //fetch amount of each item
            var item_amount=record.getLineItemValue('item', 'amount', i);
                if (item_amount != null && item_amount != '') {
                record.setLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_itemamount', i, item_amount);
        //set total amount to custom item amount field
                }
   }
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
}
```

Comment: Did test it but didn't see the value being populated yet. Am I missing something here? Does the script work on VALIDATE LINE FUNCTION? Can you test and let me know if it works?

Comment: Need to know more context. When do you want the value to auto populate. For instance, If this is a client script, why are you loading the record to read an item field, when it should already be available on the form?

Comment: Tested below client script but no change in the custom field.
 function custItemAmount(type) 

 {  
  if(type == 'edit')
   {
   //iterate over items
    for(i=1;i<=nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');i++)
    {
   //fetch amount of each item
     var item_amount=parseFloat(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','amount',i));
     
    }
   }
  nlapiSetFieldValue('custcol_item_amount',nlapiFormatCurrency(item_amount));
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to see the custom column populated? Is it after the User has added the line?  If yes, then you script is incorrect.  The script you shared looks to be a User Event script.  These types of script only execute when you either load or save a record.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with below simple script..Thanks for your help.

==
    function custItemAmount(type)

```
{  
        if(type == 'item'){

    var item_amount=parseFloat(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','amount'));   
    //nlapiSetFieldValue('custcol_item_amount',item_amount);
```

nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol_item_amount',nlapiFormatCurrency(item_amount));

}

return true;
    }